# Facebook app POST displays blank page

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, .net-4.5

I'm programming a Facebook app on localhost. When some event triggers, the user gets a notification on Facebook. The notification works great, but however when he opens it, it sends a POST request to:

`http://localhost:5939/Home/Messages/20`

and displays like this in the browser:

`https://apps.facebook.com/{FACEBOOK-APP-ID}/Home/Messages/20?fb_source=notification&ref=notif&notif_t=app_notification`

If the user is located outside the app on Facebook (but on Facebook), the app loads correctly. If the user refreshes the page while in the app, it displays correctly. However when the user is located INSIDE the app and clicks the notification, it displays a white blank page.

What could be causing this?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 .NET framework 4.5 and yes, my Messages controller function is POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed by changing the apps `Namespace` to something other than blank. Now it works.